# How to rotate HingeJoint2D by code?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I am trying to set the rotation of a HingeJoint2D by code, but the 'rotation' property is get-only. I tried setting the limits to my current rotation, but that doesn't work either. What's the proper way of doing it?

```
bowJoint.limits = new JointAngleLimits2D() { max = rotation, min = rotation };
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the angle to a fixed angle, or are you trying to set the limits that the hinge is allowed to move between? Also, for limits to mean anything, the useLimits property has to be set to TRUE

Comment: I try to set it to a fixed angle, the limits were just a workaround that I tried which didn't work.

Comment: Did you set the UseLimits property to true? If that's not set, it will ignore the limits.

Comment: I did set it to true.

Comment: Are you intending this to be a dynamic angle or fixed all the time?

Comment: Dynamic, it should always point at the mouse arrow.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to figure the same thing out.

Comment: Hi! @GohanDGeo sorry for the late answer. No I sadly did not find a solution.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution?